# Using Regex Scrape the stock Data

Tags: javascript, json, regex, xml

I have a Json File i wanted to get data of stock data in below format is it possbile to Use Regex to get it

```
[["2017-10-04",799.2,824.95,795.6,824.0,818.85,8643924.0,70161.17]

["2017-10-04",799.2,824.95,795.6,824.0,818.85,8643924.0,70161.17]]
```

i dont want Question Marks, want only first five columns with Commas.

I am using a Automation tool to Download JSON file, if i can get that format my work is Completely done withput any Coding

I am new to Regex i downloaded Expresso but hard to understand it as of now

Answer (score 0):

Your description is not clear enough, so I'm not sure what exact format do you expect of the end result. Here's the Regex that will keep the first 5 columns. `/^([^,]+,){5}/gm`

Better give a "input - output" test case, that's most efficient way to clarify your requirement.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-3QsMMhIAklcFJqNFpRNUpubDQ/view?usp=sharing

I want to get the Data Starting from [[ TO end of ]]

only First 5 columns, i did below one buy not able to remove QuotationS

\(?\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}\)?"?,?\d{0,10}\.\d{0,5}?"?,?\d{0,10}\.\d{0,5}?"?,?\d{0,10}\.\d{0,5}

Below is what i get after using above given regex 

2017-10-09",839.0,839.8,828.0
2017-10-06",824.0,839.35,822.6
2017-10-05",825.0,828.45,818.65
2017-10-04",799.2,824.95,795.6
2017-10-03",795.0,803.85,785.35
2017-09-29",791.75,793.4,779.1
2017-09-28",799.65,802.9,780.2

Comment: if you just want to get rid of that extra ", you need to use capture group. In your regex `(?\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2})?"?` I don't know what does the first `?` do, it should just render your regex invalid, so I suggest you remove it

Comment: And please, put in some effort to describe your question properly, and correct typos.

Comment: I tried using this one and it works(?\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2})?"?,?\d{0,10}\.\d{0,5}?"?,?\d{‌​0,10}\.\d{0,5}?"?,?\‌​d{0,10}\.\d{0,5}.?\d‌​{0,10}\.\d{0,5}.?\d{‌​0,10}\.\d{0,5}.?\d{0‌​,10}\.\d{0,5}.?\d{0,‌​10}\.\d{0,5}<br/> it returns like this 2017-10-09",839.0,839.8,828.0,829.25,830.65,4046109.0,33674.‌​12     without that " ? " its not working i`m using Visual Studio Code. if i get rid of those ", Nothing coming whne i compile. Sorry I am new to this website

Comment: having difficulty understand you. can you show me the code, not just the regex?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-3QsMMhIAklcFJqNFpRNUpubDQ/view?usp=sharing     please check the Attached link

Comment: I'm saying the code where you use your regex, not the raw data you wanna process. Plus, your data is already JSON, why not do a JSON parse and read the data you want directly? It's way easier then using regex.

Comment: I am directly using it on Winautomation tool, there is a property where it directly gets data after selecting a file.  winautomation.com, I already downloaded 5000 symbols data using the tool but they don't have anything to read directly from JSON.